# how to replace the '''\n''' that fgets() puts at the end of string with nothing (or '' just not \0 so the string would not be ended)?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

> My goal is to take a line from user, reverse the order of words and print it back.
> Now the logic of the code is ok and works perfectly fine, but the problem is that I
> read the line using fgets and fgets automatically puts an '\n' , I tried changing it to
> '' but I received an error, What do you suggest I do except for the easy way with a for loop that prints the string from index 1 instead of zero?
> More precisely is there a way of slicing the string as we do in python very easily?
> For example:
> `Input = I wanna ask a question` 
> `Expected output = question a ask wanna I` 
> `The output I get because the \n is replaced with \0 : question`

Comment: Per the linked duplicate: `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I receive the error identifier "buffer" is undefined, is there(except for stdio.h and string.h) any header I should include?

Comment: You mustn't copy&paste code from an answer without adapting to your code. If your array has a different name, use that name. This applies to every answer and example you will find on any webseite. They are not tailored for your code.

Comment: @Gerhardh I thought buffer was a predefined function or something similar, and now i feel stupid, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AlirezaMirzaei *now i feel stupid* That's an undocumented feature of C - the language ***will*** let you know how stupid you really are.  ;-)